# rake aborted! during setup of github pages for octopress

Tags: git, octopress, github-pages

I'm not sure if I'm going crazy or not. Trying to setup octopress on github pages. Everything is setup fine with RVM, using bundle exec for rake, but when I run setup_github_pages, I put in the read/write URL and get the following:

```
Repository url: git@github.com:ryanmccrary/ryanmccrary.github.io
rm -rf _deploy
mkdir _deploy
cd _deploy
Initialized empty Git repository in /Projects/octopress/_deploy/.git/
[master (root-commit) 2c6544e] Octopress init
1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
create mode 100644 index.html
cd -
rake aborted!
undefined local variable or method `url' for main:Object

Tasks: TOP => setup_github_pages
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the report. I just [pushed a fix](https://github.com/imathis/octopress/commit/77dc6a1ccf7ffb67ecbaecd9fd612ebdd7906d72) which should clear it up.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, Brandon. That cleared up that issue, but now "rake generate" is giving me the following:
`Configuration from /Users/rrm/Projects/octopress/_config.yml
    Building site: source -> public
    Liquid Exception: undefined method `gsub' for nil:NilClass in page
    /Users/rrm/Projects/octopress/plugins/octopress_filters.rb:123:in `shorthand_url'`

Comment: I've pushed another fix. I'm sorry for the trouble. As it turns out the blog_url method was only returning the url if it was a project page not a user pages.